# HTML overflow CSS not working

Tags: html, css, overflow

[Webpage I am referencing](http://jirachi.net/404.html)

The CSS:

```
a img {
        bottom: -30px;
        right: 0;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
        -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out; 
        -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}
a img:hover {
        transform: translate(0,-30px);
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,-30px);
        -o-transform: translate(0,-30px);
        -moz-transform: translate(0,-30px);
}
```

Image HTML:

```
<a href="index.html"><img src="images/tag.png" height="100" width="119"></img></a>
```

Viewing the webpage on a 1080p screen makes it look like there aren't any problems. But some people do have lower resolution screens.

EX:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xqXW.jpg

As you can see, the "tag" isn't sticking to the bottom of the page. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated, but your image tag is incorrect. For XHTML it should be <img src="images/tag.png" height="100" width="119"/>

Comment: @Simon yeah, I don't know why I used </img> sometimes I mindlessly write my code but thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want it to be always at the bottom of the screen, no matter what? If so,

Change:

```
position: absolute;
```

To:

```
position: fixed;
```

Comment: @dstorey - Haha, new users! They come with one problem, get a solution and vanish! Hope you get the well deserved green-tick!!